# How do I reach the top of the flag pole in the Spring Feet 1 badge challenge?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

I'm aiming to get 100% in Mario Wonder, and I've managed to 100%  every level except for the Spring Feet 1 badge challenge. No matter how hard I try, I just can't land on the top of the flag pole. I'm jumping off right at the edge of the platform, but I just don't seem to stay in the air long enough. I can only assume I'm doing something wrong.

**How do I reach the top of the flag pole in the Spring Feet 1 badge challenge?**

Comment: Posting this for anyone else who was as completely stumped by this as I was.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to air spin (with R) to get a little bit of extra air time. Once I did that, I was able to reach the top of the  flagpole on my first attempt.

I had completely forgotten about the extra air time the spin added, and only realized this was the solution with the assistance of the following video:

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I eventually realised that you need to sprint (hold down the Y button on the Switch with the default configuration) and use the spin (right button on the Switch). This gives you a lot more lateral distance with your jumps. It still took me a couple of tries but it makes all the difference.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! This answer has already been given. Please read through existing answers before giving your own. When you have enough reputation, you can comment on existing answers, to give additional information.

Comment: @Joachim The other answer makes no mention of the sprint button, only the spin button. You assumed I didn’t read it but you clearly didn’t read mine. Lol. All SO sites remain toxic.

Comment: I apologize if your answer gives additional information and if I offended you. I thought I was being nice about it. But considering this as "toxic" (which, frankly, is a judgment passed on too easily these days) seems an overreaction, as my comment was not at all intended to be malicious. Besides, this is why more votes are necessary, and no harm seems to have been done.